# Avoiding Deadlocks and TimeOuts when processing huge data

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have code in an ASP.NET form that needs to, depending on user entry create messages in the database. We are speaking of potentially thousands of db entries. How do I protect against deadlocks, I mean apart from using Transactions and setting IsolationLevel to Serializable, as well as using WITH(NOLOCK) statement on my select statements since I don't mind a dirty read.

Thanks for your answers in advance

```
Event code: 3005 Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. Event time: 10/13/2010 10:12:14 PM Event time (UTC): 10/14/2010 3:12:14 AM Event ID: a565c58a7f844692859aa21303447c7c Event sequence: 206 Event occurrence: 1 Event detail code: 0 Application information: Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/610100832/Root-12-129314933998593750 Trust level: Full Application Virtual Path: / Application Path: D:\Websites\admin.beta.sharedTime.com\ Machine name: SHAREDTIME Process information: Process ID: 3440 Process name: w3wp.exe Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Exception information: Exception type: SqlException Exception message: Transaction (Process ID 56) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. Request information: Request URL: http://beta.admin.sharedTime.com/admin_text_mass_send.aspx Request path: /admin_text_mass_send.aspx User host address: 69.211.10.138 User: Is authenticated: False Authentication Type: Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Thread information: Thread ID: 10 Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Is impersonating: False Stack trace: at mtNamespace.mt.createmessage_queue(String phone_number, String text_message, DateTime send_on, String system_name, Double user_no, Double send_priority, String message_type, Boolean returnqueue) in http://server/App_Code/mt.vb:line 1509 at ASP.admin_text_mass_send_aspx.save_user_values(Object sender, EventArgs e) in http://server/admin_text_mass_send.aspx:line 103 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Custom event details:
```

Comment: post the actual code that is throwing this exception, not just the exception

Comment: The code that throws the deadlock error is a simple insert operation to the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind dirty reads then you don't mind delayed writes either.  Use a producer/consumer queue to delay writes, make it look faster to the user, and get rid of deadlocks.

When the user submits the changes, put the changes into a queue (producer) and return immediately.  Then use a single background thread to pull out the pending changes and commit to the database.  This can come in several forms.  The simplest way is to have a `Queue` in ASP.NET that contains objects with all the data to commit.  However, you're likely to lose data from time-to-time due to ASP.NET restarts or other more critical shutdowns since pending changes are not saved anywhere.  A more reliable alternative is to use an MSMQ queue to store pending changes.  Another option is to have a custom set of "pending" database tables that you insert into with the changes to apply.  This table can be denormalized if it affects performance in your case.  The key here is it's insert only, so you won't get deadlocks.  Here to you have a single background process to move the data from this pending table to the real tables.

Comment: What if I do not want to loose data?

Comment: @Kobojunkie, if the queue is stored either in MSMQ or in a separate database table then you don't have to worry about loosing data.

Comment: WOW . .  separate? I doubt the client is going to allow any of those.

Comment: @Kobojunkie, This is a perfectly valid solution to the problem and is very safe and easy to implement.  I don't understand why a client would object but if they did out of ignorance, then you should be able to change their mind.  Really, I don't understand why a client would get involved with nitty gritty little tech details like this anyways, but everyone has a different relationship with their clients.